# oracle jdbc driver reports no primary key columns on a table that has a primary key

Tags: oracle, jdbc

This was reported by HibernateTools Reverse Engineering, but it seems to be true.

oracle jdbc driver reports no primary key columns on a table that has a primary key.

```
@Test 
public void checkTable() throws SQLException, IOException {

    System.out.println("in check table");
    assertNotNull(conn);



    Statement s = conn.createStatement();
    ResultSet rset = s.executeQuery("select user from dual");
    rset.next();
    String username = rset.getString(1);
    rset.close();
    try {
    s.execute("drop table " + username  + ".x");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // nothing it might not exist
    }

    s.execute("create table "  + username + ".x (y number)");
    s.execute("alter table x add constraint x_pk primary key (y)");

    DatabaseMetaData meta = conn.getMetaData();
    final String[] tableTypes = new String[] { "TABLE", "VIEW" };
     ResultSet rs = meta.getTables(null, username, "X",tableTypes);
    rs.next();
    String table = rs.getString("table_name");
    System.out.println("table is " + table);
    rs.close();

    rs = s.executeQuery("select * from user_constraints where table_name = 'X'");
    rs.next();
    String type = rs.getString("constraint_type");
    assertEquals("P",type);  // primary key
    rs.close();

    rs = meta.getPrimaryKeys(null, username,    "X");
    rs.next();
    logger.info("getting pk");
    System.out.print("wtf");
    int colCount = 0;
    while (rs.next()) {
        final String pkName = rs.getString("pk_name");
        logger.info("pkName: {}", pkName);
        int keySeq = rs.getShort("key_seq");  // TODO should probably be column seq
        String columnName = rs.getString("column_name");
        logger.warn("seq: {}, columnName: {}, keySeq, columnName");
        colCount++;
    }
    System.out.println("colCount: " + colCount);
    assertEquals(1,colCount);



}
```

Comment: Please don't add junk to your question just to circumvent the quality filters. You will need to provide a [mcve] and all relevent error information. I don't see how the code you post is relevant to your question, so **describe** it.

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and add the complete `create table` statement for the table in question including all constraints and indexes.